# total derivative from an equation system

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I'd like to find a partial derivative from the following equation system, but having some trouble.

I'd appreciate for some help.

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}$$

$$ x = a y - z $$
$$ y = b \sinh\bigg(\frac{x-cy}{d}\bigg) $$

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it (assuming what you have written in the question is correct), then

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}=-1.$$

Comment: thank you for your answer,
wouldn't the second equation of y = .. affect the first equation and finally affect the partial derivative?

Comment: @Newuser1010, no because the second equation only contains the variables $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I guess my question was wrong. Could you help me how the total derivative would be?